# How to create 3D curve in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I want give 3D effect to my button.

The Expected output is this :

[image: Expected]

And i have created this till now:

[image: Current-IMage]

Now as you can see the image i have created does not have that 3D effect in my button.

How to get the 3D button effect ??
Please guide me

***I dont want the shape as the expected output just the 3D effect at its borders.***

Comment: The example you posted is done with **bevel and emboss**, you should google it. I don't have time to post an answer right now but you should find satisfying youtube tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: Yes i have figured it our i am trying to recreate that using bevel and emboss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick and easy way (albeit not the best looking) would be to use a inner and outer glow combination.

I made this in about 2-3 minutes:

[image]

- Select the Clip Group
- Go to Effect > Stylize > Outer Glow and pick your desired settings
- Go to Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow and do the same